# find objects matching id parameter in json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i've got a json that contains a mixture 2 kind of objects modelA and modelB

modelA has an array that contains a mixture of both.
but modelB is single item.

both modelA and modelB has an id parameter.

what is the best and fastest way to find the object (may modelA or modelB) using id parameter and return the object.

```
{ "id": 23,
   "items":[
    {   "name":"g",
        "id":10
    },
    {
        "id":90 ,
        "items":[
            {"name":"a" , "id":11},
            {"name":"s" , "id":12},
            {"id":93 , items […]},
            {"name":"d" , "id":15},

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":92 ,
        "items":[…]
    }
   ]
}
```

modelA has id and items.

modelB has just id.

items is an array of modelA s and modelB s.

and each id is unique.

thanks.

Comment: Can you put more details about you JSON attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you have parsed you JSON file into a [String: AnyObject] swift dictionary.

**Method 1:**
If you are going to search for only one time, you can recurse the hierarchy using this code:

```
func findById(id: Int, json: [String: AnyObject]) -> [String: AnyObject]?{
    if let jsonId = json["id"] as? Int where jsonId == id{
        return json
    }
    if let jsonItems = json["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
        for jsonItem in jsonItems{
            if let item = findById(id, json: jsonItem){
                return item
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Method 2:**

If you are going to search by Id more than once, the first method would become slow. You have to flatten your JSON file and build a Dictionary with ids as keys and JSON Objects(Model A or Model B) as values:

```
func flattenHierarchy(json: [String: AnyObject], inout flatObj: [Int: [String:AnyObject]]){
    if let jsonId = json["id"] as? Int {
        flatObj[jsonId] = json
    }
    if let jsonItems = json["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
        for jsonItem in jsonItems{
            flattenHierarchy(jsonItem, flatObj: &flatObj)
        }
    }
}


var flatStructure = [Int: [String:AnyObject]]()
flattenHierarchy(json, flatObj: &flatStructure) //jsonObj is you [String: AnyObject] json

flatStructure[10] //will give you the result you want
```